# Javascript - How do i make Object.property.property a valid property?

Tags: javascript, html, function, object, properties

I currently am taking an online javascript course and it says that 
Object.property.property is a valid variable, but I cannot for the life of me find anything on the internet about it or make it work in my program. In the notes for this section, it says its possible to make a property of an object have a sub property. Here is the code that the example is referring to:

```
function car () { 
this.weight=0; 
this.engine=""; 
this.aero_factor=0; 
this.speed=0;  
}  
var porsche = new car()
```

The examples it gives when saying that "Properties can be Objects, too" are:

```
car.interiorStyle=”Type 12”; 
car.interiorStyle.upholstery=”Leather”; 
car.interiorStyle.airConditioning=true; 
car.interiorStyle.radio=”JVC”; 
car.interiorStyle.radio.power=200;
```

But that's it. It doesn't say how to implement it at all and I can't figure out why when I do it, it ends up as undefined every time.

Here is my code:

```
function Car(weight, speed, turboSpeed) {
    this.weight=weight;
    this.speed=speed;
    this.speed.turbo = turboSpeed;
}
var porsche = new Car(1750, 125, 250);
alert(porsche.weight); //1750
alert(porsche.speed); //125
alert(porsche.speed.turbo); //undefined
```

If I could get some help with this that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: You can always define object.property.property as long as property is not applied on primitive type property

Comment: You need to define `speed` as a object then assign properties to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost right. when they say "also" they mean you can assign an object to them like this:

```
this.speed={normal:55,turbo:95};
```

so then `this.speed.normal==55`, and `this.speed.turbo==95`

Comment: Thanks very much. This makes a lot more sense to me now. Got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always define object.property.property as long as you don't define property on propety of primitive type